# what is the url to get the user profile from google?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have retrieved an access token from google and a given id:

```
token: ya29.ImCCBxMGz6nKCpuhOxRTxFHufy63dR9AXAoOEyvq5_ZDVCVJzrUTXNi1c4fF5pOD0DXESrnvpzqPdXLQPRU3C8V8v5xww

id:
11187089746417917076
```

what url do I use to check for the user's email and profile?

Comment: In the case of the access token, when the expiration time was over, `Invalid Value` is returned with oauth2.tokeninfo. So unfortunately, the information cannot be retrieved. By the way, what is the ID?

Comment: I figured it out. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something about it here: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/signing-in-with-google/verifying-the-user-info/

It is a get request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo with `{"Authorization": "Bearer <TOKEN>"}` in the header. Note the space between `Bearer` and `<TOKEN>`. There is no need to pass along the `user id`.